# run time check function

Tags: python, time

I know I can use time module to track the run-time of my codes:

For example if I have this fibonacci function with recursion

```
def fib_gen_r(i):
    """
    Fibonacci function generator
    generate the fibonacci number at 'i'th posistion
    """
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    elif i == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib_gen_r(i - 1) + fib_gen_r(i - 2)
```

I can do this:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
print(fib_gen_r(35))
print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time}s seconds ---\n")
# >>> 
# 9227465
# --- 2.556117296218872s seconds ---
```

But, if I don't want to write this everytime, I wrote a function:

```
def time_spend(code_to_check):
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    print(code_to_check)
    print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time}s seconds ---\n")

time_spend(fib_gen_r(35))
# >>>
# check run-time:
# 9227465
# --- 0.0s seconds ---
```

Somehow, it is not reading the run-time, what did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: "I know I can use time module to track the run-time of my codes" Well, you _can_, but you shouldn't. The `time` module is not intended for benchmarking or profiling code; use `timeit` or `profile`, respectively. They take care of all kinds of things that you wouldn't think of, or that would be a pain to write—running the test multiple times and averaging appropriately, using the right clock for the platform, disabling background tasks like the GC cycle detector, not counting setup code as part of what you're timing, etc.

Comment: I do know timeit as well, sometimes it is a little bit redundant

Comment: How is it "redundant"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your `fib_gen_r` function **before** calling the `time_spend`. Instead, you have to pass the actual function as parameter, without calling it, and call it inside `time_spend`.

This code `time_spend(fib_gen_r(35))` calls `fib_gen_r` first, and after it finishes, passes the result to `time_spend`. Not what you want as you can't measure what is already finished. Instead you want to use this syntax `time_spend(fib_gen_r, 35)` to pass the actual, function object as parameter, **without calling it**, so it can be called inside the function:

```
def time_spend(code_to_check, *args, **kwds):
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    result = code_to_check(*args, **kwds)
    print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time}s seconds ---\n")
    return result


time_spend(fib_gen_r, 35)
```

An easier alternative is to use the context manager (`with` statements):

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def time_spend():
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    yield
    print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time}s seconds ---\n")
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
with time_spend():
    fib_gen_r(35)
```

Comment: wait, I did run code to check, because it actually took the time, to calculate, and even print it out

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Oh I got it, edited the answer to clarify

Comment: I see!!! I am indeed calling it before the time_spent, and that is exactly why, even it took time to get executed, but that was before the whole time_spent() runs. With your method, I am enforcing the fib function to run after I start timing, thank you!